# MVC view is calling controller method not properly

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am building a store locator in MVC. Here is my controller:

```
namespace IWOOv4.Controllers
{
  public class StoreListingController : Controller
  {
    // GET: StoreListing
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Details(string zip)
    {
        List<Site> result = SiteMgmt.GetByZip(zip);
        View().ViewData["sites"] = result;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Details(string city, string st)
    {
        List<Site> result = SiteMgmt.GetByCity(city, st);
        View().ViewData["sites"] = result;
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my View:

```html
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!--HEADER-->
  </div>
  <div class="row sub-header">
    <span>ONLINE ORDERING</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row container-text">
    Find Your Store
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
      <div class="input-group-btn">        
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="searchbutton">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!--FOOTER-->
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchbutton').on('click', function (event) {
      document.location = '@Url.Action("Details", "StoreListingController")';
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I am calling my Controller action, it does not display my store listing. It changes my URL from `http://localhost/IWOOv4/Home/Index` to `http://localhost/IWOOv4/StoreListingController/Details`. I looked up how to call a controller action to your view and the way I have it seems okay.. What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the `Controller` suffix to the second parameter of `Url.Action`, MVC will do that for you when creating the route:

```
document.location = '@Url.Action("Details", "StoreListing")';
```

Comment: I took the StoreListingController off as the second parameter and now when I search a zip code it gives the error code and changes the URL to http://localhost/IWOOv4/Home/Details. Is it suppose to change the URL? The Details action is suppose to list me out the stores once I search for zip or city.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown which would cause that behaviour.

Comment: So could it be in the controller? I am just trying to refresh my memory of MVC. I haven't used it in over a year. I am so lost and I have spent hours trying to resolve this issue. I am at a stop halt with my task at this point. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a maximum of 2 action methods with the same name on a controller, and in order to do that, 1 must be [HttpPost], and the other must be [HttpGet]

You might want to check the answers here:

[Routing: The current request for action [...] is ambiguous between the following action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668105/routing-the-current-request-for-action-is-ambiguous-between-the-following)

[The current request for action [...] on controller type '...' is ambiguous between the following action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187833/the-current-request-for-action-on-controller-type-is-ambiguous-betwe)